# How can I change the locale used by IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, locale, resourcebundle

I tried creating a new Gradle project with IntelliJ IDEA (11.1.3 Community Edition). Unfortunately, I am confronted with this error:

[image]

The IDE log reveals this error:

```
2012-08-19 06:48:50,873 [ 735372]   WARN - .plugins.gradle.util.GradleLog - java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name i18n.GradleBundle, locale en_CA
```

No big surprise there.

I am not sure how IntelliJ IDEA determines which locale to use, but it correctly determined that I live in Canada. I tried to change the locale to en_US by passing the following command line flags to the JVM in the `idea.sh` shell script:

```
# Adam's custom args:
LOCALE_ARGS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.variant=US"

ALL_JVM_ARGS="$LOCALE_ARGS $VM_OPTIONS $COMMON_JVM_ARGS $IDE_JVM_ARGS $AGENT $REQUIRED_JVM_ARGS"
```

Unfortunately, it still insists on using en_CA.

**How do I change the locale used by IntelliJ IDEA?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in `idea.log` indicates that the Grade plugin itself does not reuse IDEA's system properties. This is a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73107) verified by JetBrains and you can vote for it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately IDEA is still insisting on `en_CA` (even with `LOCALE_ARGS="-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Duser.variant=US -Duser.region=US"`). :(

Comment: You can confirm once and for all which locale IDEA uses by installing and using the [System Properties](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=15) plugin. The error message in `idea.log` indicates that the Grade plugin itself does not reuse IDEA's system properties.

Comment: Great find! How about you edit your answer to include that bug and I will accept it?

Comment: As a workaround you can copy the `GradleBundle.properties` to `GradleBundles_en_CA.properties` **inside** the `idea/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar`, and restart IDEA.

Answer (score 4):

This won't help with the gradle bug mentioned in the answer (which I dunno might be fixed by now) but here's how I changed the Locale used by IntelliJ itself

Help --> Edit Custom VM Options

append these three lines

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Duser.variant=US
```

save and restart IntelliJ